# Notifications in Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, push-notification

What's the best way to build daily browser notifications into a Django app?

I've tried [django-webpush](https://github.com/safwanrahman/django-webpush) but it hasn't worked for me.

My issue at the moment is that users aren't correctly subscribing to push notifications. I followed the instructions for settings.py, adding 'webpush' to installed apps and adding VAPID keys (public/private.pem).

```
base.html:
{% load static %} 
{% load webpush_notifications %} 
<html> 
<head> 
  {% webpush_header %} 
</head> 
<body> 
  <p> Notifications </p> 
    {% webpush_button %} 
</body> 
</html>
```

urls.py:

```
 urlpatterns = [ 
    .... 
    path('webpush/', include('webpush.urls')),
    ]
```

Then I'm importing send_user_notification and calling send_user_notification(user=user3, payload=payload, ttl=1000)

I'm not receiving an error but the command prompt is showing that nothing is registering when I click to subscribe for push notifications. I tried commenting out the VAPID keys and it had no impact either interestingly...

Comment: Please add more details, including code you have tried and errors you have received.

Comment: I edited my comment!